# Vertical Alignment of multiple lines

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, tablecell

I know this question has been asked before. However, I do not seem to find my mistake.

I set up a plnkr. I try to align some text vertically, whereas the the stuff that needs to be aligned  is nested into multiple divs.

```
<div class="news col-md-12"  id="detailsView" >
  <div class="col-md-8 ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 widthInDetails">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8" id="newsDetails">
            Hello I am fine and how are your (I am good too)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my CSS I have this.

```
.news{
  background-color:black;
  line-height:200px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:table;
}
#newsDetails{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

So basically I have I lineheight given from the outer div with class="news". I want the the nested div to be aligned vertically. Is there any way to do this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/cMaCrG1Y8Ky48HwtgNPk?p=preview

Comment: Can the height of newsDetails be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the display: table property, you should set it in the parent node, like:

```
<div class="news col-md-12"  id="detailsView" >
  <div class="col-md-8 ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 widthInDetails">
        <div id="newsParent" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8" id="newsDetails">
            Hello I am fine and how are your (I am good too)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.news{
  background-color:black;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#newsParent {
  display:table;    
}

#newsDetails{
  height: 200px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: it works in the plnkr...but there must be something wrong in my actual code. I guess I'll have to go over it...Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes CSS can be painful.. Good luck with that and glad if it helped! :)

Comment: I found out that I had to add float:none to the news details. Then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can make wrapper `display: table` and child div `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`. find the below jsfiddle demo.

HTML

```
<div class="news col-md-12"  id="detailsView" >
  <div class="col-md-8 ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 widthInDetails">
        <div class="row newsDetailswrap">
          <div class="col-md-8" id="newsDetails">
            Hello I am fine and how are you?</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.newsDetailswrap{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    display:table;
}
#newsDetails{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhbnywq1/

Comment: The problem with your code now seems that you only have one line of text and not multiple anymore. But in my case I have to stick with the width of 200px. Therefore, part of the text has to go the second line